# Does $a \mid bc$ imply $\frac{a}{(a,b)} \mid c$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

If $a \mid bc$, then does $\frac{a}{(a,b)} \mid c$? I doubt anybody here is industrious enough to show this via a diagram, but who knows.

Comment: I think almost every time I ask someone to draw a diagram they never know what to do or always complain that diagrams don't apply.

Comment: The below diagram, as you can see, suffices to show the desired property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set $d=(a,b)$, $a=a'd, b=b'd$.  We have $(a',b')=1$.  Now, the hypothesis is $a|bc$, or $a'd|b'dc$.  Cancelling $d$, we get $a'|b'c$.  Since $(a',b')=1$, $a'|c$.

Diagram: 
[image]

Comment: I guess I was just saying that it might be interesting to develop a micro field of mathematics within a sub-field of mathematics that shows modular arithmetic and the properties of numbers with diagrams.